# Unable to save retrieved data into MongoDB - Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, telethon

I am retrieving data from telegram, it is being retrieved successfully but how can I save it into MongoDB.

```
for chat in chats:
with TelegramClient('sessionx', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    for message in client.iter_messages(chat, offset_date=datetime.date(2022, 11, 11), reverse=True):
        print(message)
        data = {"group": chat, "sender": message.sender_id,
                "text": message.text, "date": message.date}

        temp_df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[1])
        df = df.append(temp_df)
```

collection.insert_many(df)[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YcqU.png)

Comment: Please include the error in the question itself, rather than a separate image service, as the picture may be lost, making it harder for future readers to find if this is their problem too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible error :

`df` is defined as a pandas `DataFrame` or else, it might not be able to parse your object to save it in mongo. Quick reminder, mongodb accept document following the BSON format.

You could do something like this :

```
my_list = []
for chat in chats:
    with TelegramClient('sessionx', api_id, api_hash) as client:
        for message in client.iter_messages(chat, offset_date=datetime.date(2022, 11, 11), reverse=True):
            print(message)
            my_list.append({"group": chat, "sender": message.sender_id, "text": message.text, "date": message.date})

collection.insert_many(my_list)
```

Comment: if we append full message which consists of arrays in array, it shows this error "document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping"

Comment: "my_list" variable is list, but i want it to convert into dict, so with this line "some_dict = dict(my_list)" i get following error. "cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence"

Comment: Maybe show your data and what you want to achieve  with it.  It's not clear for me what you have atm, and what you are trying to get. 
Maybe create another question if it's another problem.